# linear algebra problem in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have no idea how to approch this, any help will be greatly appreciated:

Given:

Matrix A of order $(k\times n)$

Matrix B of order $(n\times k)$

with $k\neq n$,

prove that its not possible for $BA=I_n$ and $AB=I_k$ at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*: Let $k < n.$ Then $n=\text{rank}(I_n)=\text{rank}(BA) \leq \min\{\text{rank}(B), \text{rank}(A)\} \leq k.$  Use the other relation for eliminating $k > n$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $k<n$, then rank of $A$ and $B$ are both less than or equal to $k$.

Let's consider $BA=I_n$.

Suppose a sequence of $n\times n$ elementary row matrices can reduce $B$ to its row echelon form. We apply this sequence of matrices on both sides of the equation.

At least the last row of the reduced row echelon form will be all zeros. However the right hand side is the product of these elementary matrices, which is a contradiction.